# Improve efficiency of prefetch_related

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to improve the efficiency of a prefetch_related query. The models I'm using are employees and groups. There are many employees, but not so many groups.

The query looks like this:

```
Employee.objects.all().prefetch_related('group_set')
```

The SQL that is being generated looks for all groups that are connected to any of the employees. This turns out to be inefficient because I really just want to get all groups. However, the SQL has a list of employee ids that is quite long. The end of the SQL says

```
"employee_id" IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,...)
```

This list of ids can be quite long.

Is there any way to remove the "IN" clause at the end of the SQL?

Comment: There's a related ticket, [#25464](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25464).

Comment: @Alasdair got it. That ticket covers what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Alasdair answered in the comments, this issue has a related django ticket. [#25464](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25464)